# Very Simple Rails Migrate Concept

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I feel like this is a super easy question,but I've looked around and cant find an answer.
I have a running rails app that I am very fond of. It has 3 or 4 models with data that I do not want to erase or replace.

While building the app, when I added new features, I would just do a:

```
git push heroku
heroku pg:reset DATABASE
heroku run rails db:migrate
heroku run rails db:seed
```

Obviously I dont want to do that because it would erase my data.

I do have a new table/model I want to add now. It does not interact with the other models.

Would I just do:

```
git push heroku
heroku run rails db:migrate
```

And the rest of my data is okay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing: if you have important data, as always, **make backups before you deploy**. Make sure those backups are stored somewhere off of the server in case you *really* botch things and trash the machine so completely it loses everything. Make sure these backups *work* and contain all the data you expect them to. Prepare for the worst possible outcome: Every system you deploy to explodes.

Now presuming you're doing things properly, which means once you've applied migrations you no longer make any changes to them in your source code, then you should be able to cleanly apply *new* migrations with `db:migrate`.

You'll want to test that this works beforehand. If you've made a backup of the production schema, you should test against that first so there's no ugly surprises when it comes time to deploy. If everything checks out you can go live.

`pg:reset` should never be used on a production system. It can and will trash all your data. That's only really useful on your development system as a quick way of scrubbing test data and rebuilding a clean database.